# I've created a Makefile in c that should creates more than one executable, but it does not work

Tags: c, makefile

**WHAT I NEED TO DO**

I'm trying to create a Makefile in c that should create three executable from three different .c files.
I'll want to  create Lez4Es1, Lez4Es1v2 and Lez4Es3 as my executable compiling and linking in two different stages.
Something as:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic Lez4Es1.c -c
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic Lez4Es1.o -o Lez4Es1

gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic Lez4Es1v2.c -c
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic Lez4Es1.v2 -o Lez4Es1v2

gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic Lez4Es3.c -c
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic Lez4Es3.o -o Lez4Es3
```

**MY SOLUTION**

Assuming to have all .c files in the same directory i created this Makefile but it does not work:

```
CC      =   gcc

CFLAGS      +=  -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -g

TARGETS     =   Lez4Es1     \
                Lez4Es1v2   \
                Lez4Es3     \

.PHONY: all clean cleanall  

% : %.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $^ -o $@  

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

all : $(TARGETS)

clean : 
    -rm *.o *~ core

cleanall : 
    -rm *.o *.txt -f $(TARGETS) *~ core
```

**PROBLEMS**

When i run $ make it creates executable from .c file and not from .o, this is output of compiler:

```
$ make
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -g    Lez4Es1.c   -o Lez4Es1
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -g    Lez4Es1v2.c   -o Lez4Es1v2
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -g    Lez4Es3.c   -o Lez4Es3
```

How to fix to let him do the things i want to do?
There is a method to give executable files a different name than .o files?

Sorry for my bad english and if i didn't explain it well i'm ready to edit it and give you more details, thank you.

Comment: There's a built-in rule to create an executable from a `.c` file; it is being given precedence over your rules.  Why do you want the more complex, two-phase compilation?  Can you list the `.o` files as targets too?  That may or may not help; it will at least give you the `.o` files that you seem to want.  (`OBJECTS = $(TARGETS:=.o)` as a macro; add `$(OBJECTS)` before `$(TARGETS)` on the `all` dependency line.

Comment: I need the two-phase compilation because is an homework for university.

Comment: Maybe you can use `make -r` to suppress there built-in rules.  You might need to add a `.SUFFIXES: .c .o`  rule line.

Comment: It work running with $ make -r, nice tip! But i need to run as $ make.
What do .SUFFIXES: .c .o do? Thank you.

Comment: The [GNU `make` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) has a section on [Suffix Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules), which documents what `.SUFFIXES` does.  You may not need it with the pattern-style `% : %.o` rules.

Comment: Incidentally, if you have requirements like "the command line must be just `make`", you should state that in the question.  I didn't try to give an answer (these are comments, not answers), but it is really frustrating if you spend time on an answer only to be told "oh, but I can't use that because of some silly rule imposed on you by the person setting the homework".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting the built-in rule that creates executables from source files:

```
% : %.c
```

(a pattern rule with no recipe cancels that rule).